# Traversing a singly list

Tags: linked-list, traversal

While traversing a singly list, inside the loop condition, whats the difference between temp != NULL and temp-next != NULL? For Ex

```
    while(temp != NULL)
    { 
        ......
        ......
    }
```

and

```
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    { 
        ......
        ......
    }
```

I don't understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

From context this answer assumes that temp is a node in the linked list.

`temp->next != NULL` returns true when there is a node after temp (i.e. when temp is not the last node in the list). As an example, consider this list:

```
a -> b -> c -> NULL
```

if we do `temp = a->next` then temp is b, and `temp->next != NULL` evaluates to true since c (not NULL) comes after b.

`temp != NULL` returns true when temp itself is a node in the list. This might not be the case if, for some reason, you have traversed too far down the list. Using the same list as above: if we do `temp = c->next`, then `temp != NULL` evaluates to false.

**Understanding that, the difference between the lists is as follows:**

- `while(temp != NULL)...` executes until temp is NULL
- `while(temp->next != NULL)` executes until the node after temp is NULL